# Typescript accessing root namespace from within a namespace

Tags: typescript

I am trying to set up some typescript definition files, and stumbled upon a very interesting problem. Inside a namespace (`a`), I want to access a member of a different namespace (`b.Clazz`). This works, but only as long as there exists no nested namespace (`a.b`). If there is no such nested namespace, TS is able to resolve this dependency. If there is such a namespace, it interprets the return type `b.Clazz` as local to `a`, and then shows the error that there is no `a.b.Clazz`. Minimal example:

```js
declare namespace a {
    function foo(): b.Clazz
    namespace b {
        // remove this empty namespace to remove the error
    }
}

declare namespace b {
    export class Clazz {

    }
}
```

How can I prevent this from happening? How can I annotate function `foo` to actually refer to the global namespace `b`?

Answer (score 0):

When the goal is to have independent namespaces `b` and `a.b`, I have had success accessing the outer namespace `b` from inside `a` via [`globalThis`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis) variable, which is a pointer to the global scope.

```
declare namespace a {
  function foo(): globalThis.b.Clazz
  namespace b { }
}

declare namespace b {
  export class Clazz { }
}

a.foo() //  function a.foo(): b.Clazz
```

By the way: While `globalThis` implementation is [not so well supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis#Browser_compatibility) amongst browsers, we just use the *type* here to reach outside of namespace `a`, so compatibility doesn't matter for the runtime anyway.